# Matlab imshow update the displayed image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have displayed an image using `imshow (myImage)`and GUIDE GUI (open an image using  `uiOpenFile` and it will be displayed automatically). My question is how can I remove the old displayed image and display another one in the same figure using Matlab.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to specify the 'Parent' property in subsequent calls to `imshow`.  For instance, if you have an image variable called 'myimg', and the handle to the axes in which the image is currently displayed is in a variable called 'imgaxes', the call would be:

```
imshow(myimg, 'Parent', imgaxes);
```

The thing you may need to figure out is the handle to the axes currently containing the image. If you capture the handle to the 'image' object when you call imshow the first time, this is easy.  That would look like:

```
h = imshow(myimg);
imshow(myimg2, 'Parent', h.Parent);
```

The second call to imshow will place the second image into the same axes as the first.

Answer (score 0):

u have to use 'parent' try:

```
imshow('bta3.jpg','Parent',handles.axes5)
```

this is the way that you can show image in target axes